Recomposition not working as i expect, image not displaying
i make composable EventCard items that gets an image from API(I get from API in bitmap because the image URL was token protected). But the cards sometimes display all default images, and sometimes all cards display an image from one card.
Like this:

then when i scroll up:

My event card code is here:
@Composable
fun EventsScreen(navController: NavHostController, user: User?) {
    val viewModel: EventViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val events by viewModel.events.collectAsState()

    val category by remember { mutableStateOf(EventCategory.EDUCATIVE) }
    var search by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    BaseComponent(navController, user, "Listado Eventos", false) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(12.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    value = search,
                    onValueChange = {
                        search = it
                        viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                            viewModel.getEvents(search)
                        }
                    },
                    label = {
                        Text("Buscar")
                    },
                    placeholder = {
                        Text("Curso de ...")
                    }
                )
            }
            Row {
                /* TODO busqueda por categoria */
            }
            Row {
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                    userScrollEnabled = true,
                ) {
                    items(events.content) { event ->
                        key (event.id) {
                            EventCard(navController, event)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Here is the card code:
package frgp.utn.edu.ar.quepasa.presentation.ui.components.events.card

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.border
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material3.CardDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.ElevatedCard
import androidx.compose.material3.HorizontalDivider
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.asImageBitmap
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextOverflow
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import coil3.compose.AsyncImage
import frgp.utn.edu.ar.quepasa.R
import frgp.utn.edu.ar.quepasa.data.model.Event
import frgp.utn.edu.ar.quepasa.presentation.ui.components.events.card.components.CardButtonsBar
import frgp.utn.edu.ar.quepasa.presentation.ui.components.text.ReadMoreText
import frgp.utn.edu.ar.quepasa.presentation.viewmodel.media.EventPictureViewModel
import frgp.utn.edu.ar.quepasa.presentation.viewmodel.media.PictureViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@Composable
fun EventCard(navController: NavHostController, event: Event) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val eventPictureViewModel: EventPictureViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val pictureViewModel: PictureViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val bitmap by pictureViewModel.bitmap.collectAsState()
    val pictures by eventPictureViewModel.pictures.collectAsState()
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        eventPictureViewModel.getPicturesByEvent(event.id!!)
        pictures.content.firstOrNull()
            ?.let { pictureViewModel.setPictureBitmap(it.id) }
    }
    ElevatedCard(
        onClick = {
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Card Clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            navController.navigate("eventDetailedScreen/${event.id}")
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(IntrinsicSize.Max),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(
            defaultElevation = 6.dp
        ),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer
        )
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(4.dp),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            Column {
                if (bitmap != null && pictures.content.firstOrNull() != null) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = bitmap,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(100.dp)
                            .border(
                                1.dp,
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
                                RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                            ).clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
                        contentDescription = "Event Image",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    )
                } else {
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.baseline_broken_image_24),
                                modifier = Modifier
                                .size(100.dp)
                            .border(
                                1.dp,
                                MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary,
                                RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
                            ).clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium),
                        contentDescription = "No Image",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    )
                }
            }
            Column {
                event.title?.let {
                    Text(
                        text = it,
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                        maxLines = 1
                    )
                }
                HorizontalDivider(
                    thickness = 2.dp,
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
                )
                event.description?.let {
                    ReadMoreText(
                        it,
                        Modifier.padding(16.dp), MaterialTheme.typography.bodyLarge,
                        1,
                        10
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        event.votes?.let { event.id?.let { id -> CardButtonsBar(id, it) } }
    }
}

pictureViewModel code:
@HiltViewModel
class PictureViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PictureRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _bitmap = MutableStateFlow<Bitmap?>(null)
    val bitmap = _bitmap.asStateFlow()
    fun setBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        _bitmap.value = bitmap
    }

    private val _pictures = MutableStateFlow<List<Bitmap?>>(emptyList())
    val pictures = _pictures.asStateFlow()

    fun setPictureBitmap(pictureId: UUID) {
        repository.viewPicture(pictureId, onComplete = {
            _bitmap.value = it
        })
    }

    fun setPicturesBitmap(pictureIds: List<UUID>) {
        val bitmaps = mutableListOf<Bitmap?>()
        pictureIds.forEach { pictureId ->
            repository.viewPicture(pictureId, onComplete = {
                bitmaps.add(it)
                _pictures.value = bitmaps
            })
        }
    }
}

EventViewModel gets the list of events from API
I dont get what i am doing wrong, thanks in advance!

Every EventCard uses the same ViewModel so the same PictureViewModel.bitmap is used in every card. You should save the Bitmap in the Event model, so each Event will have its Image.
